# How to register JavaScript using VB.NET code

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I am using this code ..

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(control, GetType(Button), "sas", "<script> alert('Inserted successfully');</script>", True)
```

but html result is :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    <script> alert('Inserted successfully');</script>
//]]>;
```

why ?
 and do  I need to call it only in `Page_Load` or can do that in button click event ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last setting which is set to true is for automatically injecting `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags.  Remove your script tags or set that flag to false.